# Get common data from multiple arrays of object that containing a unique id and nested array using javascript es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find the common data from multiple arrays of object that contains a unique id (mongoose object id) and an array of string.

for example:

```
array1 = [{
             _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c04",
             date: "2021-07-15T12:18:12.223Z",
             time: "30",
             hours: ["8:00 AM", "8:30 AM"]
        }]
array2 = [{
             _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c05",
             date: "2021-07-15T12:18:12.223Z",
             time: "60",
             hours: ["7:30 AM", "8:30 AM", "9:30AM"]
        }]
array3 = [{
             _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c06",
             date: "2021-07-16T12:12:12.223Z",
             time: "30",
             hours: ["7:00 AM", "8:30 AM"]
        }]
```

The output should have maximum common values in the arrays for maximum common dates and that date should have maximum common hour.

So the sample output should look something like this.

```
common_data = {
    date: "2021-07-15T12:18:12.223Z",
    time: "30",
    hours: "8:30AM"
}
```

I looked up at other answers and tried something like this:
merged all the arrays and

```
let result = merged_slots_array.shift().filter(function(v) {
    return merged_slots_array.every(function(a) {
        const matchDate = a.date === v.date;
        const getMatchTime = a.hours.shift().filter(function(x) {
            return v.hours.every(function(t) {
                return x.indexOf(t) !== -1;
            })
        });
        return matchDate && getMatchTime
    });
});
```

but getting error `merged_slots_array.shift(...).filter is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After concatenating the arrays, finding the max common hour can be done through a filter that only keeps duplicates, then gets sorted. Once we have that, we can query each array to make sure it contains the max hour, then extract the max date and time. My output was slightly different than yours because i filtered for the max time, hour and date

```js
array1 = [{
  _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c04",
  date: "2021-07-15T12:18:12.223Z",
  time: "30",
  hours: ["8:00 AM", "8:30 AM"]
}]
array2 = [{
  _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c05",
  date: "2021-07-15T12:18:12.223Z",
  time: "60",
  hours: ["7:30 AM", "8:30 AM", "9:30AM"]
}]
array3 = [{
  _id: "60f027f98b55eb2df1f36c06",
  date: "2021-07-16T12:12:12.223Z",
  time: "30",
  hours: ["7:00 AM", "8:30 AM"]
}]

const getCommon = (arrays) => {
let group = [].concat.apply([], [...arrays])
let hour = group.map(e=>e.hours).flat().filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i).sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))[0]
let common = group.filter(e=>e.hours.includes(hour))
let time = Math.max(...common.map(e => +e.time))
let date = common.map(e => e.date).sort((a,b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a))[0];
return {date: date, time: time, hours: [hour]}
}
let arg = []
arg.push(array1)
arg.push(array2)
arg.push(array3)
console.log(getCommon(arg))
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjUE8CMAuKA7BEC8EDaA3gFAQQD6AlgCYoQBEAbAAwBmTATAOwsCcAHACMArEJAD2VFkhYBmBgGMmAFjoAaEhCpQwIWnXYckAWiacjSIQBUk7FEj532AOnbsZALTUawFALa76GSYvUgALAHsAVxgAZ1o8OgcmJggAQQBZNXoHILTMgF0iAF9C0EhYeARbDCxcQg1KGnpmNi5eQRExCSlZBSYhEM1tAP1DEzMLa1t7Rxc3T3VSH389ZkGI6Lj8Ok4UXIysxL2Ug9V6HmODwpKiMug4RBk0TBx8YlJG1dYObn5hUXEkmkckUDEGWh0egM7GMpnMDCmjlmrg8g2WIyC6yisXiOxQyTyhxyJwKxUKRHk4XQMUgAHNwABhcK%20XxU561CAACgqiDiNQAlDgAHwQYh3WkwKIAB3Zrzw%20SclPQ8m0TigUqlwAQnPlZzwTgNPIQMXy-Nu4AgGxgKBpMAo6Fprwl0qcvnVnJA2CFICcVpi-KcLGA2k5AZYFGAOhgnI9qgoqiggq90Cc9qoIAAHgB5FgewUAQmwuAoAZi4RgYBjUFUAiTIqgTmA4RVoCZvilsBAnNr-LwTFKFspLLZNSdksiUsDEajHq9Pr9qeVwEi6ZinKt-LNd3RKHQkV8AhAMFe6W0oVdUAznINiuZrPQF6lHuFEAA1D70ZvzZAIbpbfbHVwId70fZ9kx9X9S3LStuRrOsIHQEAAHcIAAEWGbtBSMBDkLQjDE17fsAG4iBgcBonQUVf1oX8zh3CB0TOP14itfIimKIgKSpMtQEbcJaU5ekwDbe8dSNJAEweKpJMqGRTX5IA)

Comment: Getting this error in typescript `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type` on line `let date = common.map(e => e.date).sort((a,b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a))[0];`

Comment: Just set it to type:any. Take a look at the ts playground link I added to my answer.

Comment: I am trying to do it like getting the array in a loop so using `merged_slots_array.push(slots);`

then doing `let found = this.getCommon(merged_slots_array)` but getting undefined.
`{ date: undefined, time: -Infinity, hours: [ undefined ] }` as returned value;

Comment: I updated my answer to show 3 pushes but really it didn't change anything. I don't suppose you could share a link to a working example? or can you show me what your `merged_slots_array` looks like when you feed it into `getCommon`?

Comment: I am getting a common date in return which was not even in the array. How so?

Comment: I don't see how. Though we're comparing dates using a date object, there's nothing in the script that actually replaces the date string. It should only come from the original data object

Comment: Actually, the common should be fetch like first get the common date first, then in that date for each user check the common time, and for that date common duration. Sometimes I get correct values and sometimes not, why is that?